# Watin Unable to selectdate from calender

Tags: calendar, watin

I am unable to select date using watin from the following calender

https://members.myactivesg.com/facilities/view/activity/207/venue/355?time_from=1411315200

any one please help ??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the calendar ID textbox changes on every page load so you need to look for an alternative way to identify that particular element (a textbox in this case) and the way to do it, in this case is using the class. The class for that particular textbox it has datepicker AND hasDatepicker so searching an element with those two classes brings the correct textbox and then you can assign the date you need in the format the page expects it.

```
        ie2.GoTo("https://members.myactivesg.com/facilities/view/activity/207/venue/355?time_from=1411315200");
        TextField t = ie2.TextField(Find.ByClass(p => p.Equals("datepicker hasDatepicker")));
        t.Value = "The date you need in the format they expect";
```

Comment: Assuming that a dropdown list will show up based on the selected date. I can assign the value to the textfield but it doesnt trigger the dropdown list for options. any thought?

Comment: It depends on the implementation but you can try doing a t.Focus(); to see if that triggers the dropdown. You have to experiment yourself, doing it by hand and pay attention to what triggers the drop down to be shown, then you can do it programmatically. Let me know if it works.